# Terraform variable error : The given value is not valid

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

I am trying to create a monitoring alert policy using terraform. But in the plan stage i am getting the below error on the variable. Has anyone faced a similar issue in the past ? I am new to terraform and i can trying to create a iterable resource for monitoring alert policy in gcp.

```
  Error: Invalid value for input variable
│ 
│   on terraform.tfvars line 149:
│  149: alert_policies =  {
│  150:   "composer_alert" = {
│  151:     combiner     = "OR"
│  152:     display_name = "Alert Strategy"
│  153:     enabled      = "true"
│  154:     conditions = [
│  155:     {display_name         = "Bytes used condition"
│  156:     conditions_threshold = {
│  157:          "1"               = {
│  158:       comparison           = "COMPARISON_GT"
│  159:       duration             = "0s"
│  160:       filter               = "resource.type = \"cloud_composer_environment\" AND resource.labels.project_id = \"prj-comp-01\" AND metric.type = \"composer.googleapis.com/environment/database/disk/bytes_used\""
│  161:       threshold_value      = 1600000000
│  162:       alignment_period     = "300s"
│  163:       cross_series_reducer = "REDUCE_NONE"
│  164:       group_by_fields =       ["project_id"]
│  165:       per_series_aligner   = "ALIGN_MEAN"
│  166:       trigger_count        = 1
│  167:       trigger_percent      = 100 
│  168:           }
│  169:         }
│  170:       }
│  171:     ]
│  172:     notification_channels = [
│  173:     "projects/prj-test-01/notificationChannels/2276385315451985010"
│  174:     ]
│  175:   }
│  176:   }
│ 
│ The given value is not valid for variable "alert_policies": a number is
│ required.
╵
╷
│ Error: Incorrect variable type
│ 
│   on variables.tf line 392:
│  392: variable "alert_policies" {
│ 
│ The resolved value of variable "alert_policies" is not appropriate: a
│ number is required.
```

******Variables.tf**********

```
variable "alert_policies" {
  type = map(object({
    combiner     = optional(string)
    display_name = optional(string)
    enabled      = optional(bool)
    uptime_checks = optional(map(object({
      duration          = number
      uptime_check_name = string
      ssl_expiry_checks = optional(list(object({
        days_left = number
      })))
    })))
    conditions = list(object({
      display_name         = string
      conditions_threshold = map(object({
      comparison           = string
      duration             = number
      filter               = string
      threshold_value      = number
      alignment_period     = number
      cross_series_reducer = string
      group_by_fields      = list(string)
      per_series_aligner   = string
      trigger_count        = number
      trigger_percent      = number
    }))
    notification_channels = optional(list(string))
  }))
}))
}
```

╵

Comment: What is the actual `alert_policies` value that you are using?

Comment: Am I correctly understanding that you tried to define the entire google_monitoring_alert_policy resource as a single variable type in your own Variables.tf file? What exactly are you hoping to achieve with that, if it is identical to the existing resource, so why not just directly use that resource?

Comment: @Marcin I am passing the value "composer alert" in the tfvars file.

Comment: @somethingsomething I am trying to use this variable in for loop incase we have multiple alert policies to be configured.

Comment: I realised what the error was . The variable declaration for alignment period and duration is set to number but I was passing a string. Made the changes and the error went away !